# Microsoft Graph API calls giving invalid remote certificate error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, tls1.2, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail, tls1.0

I am using Microsoft Graph API to send and read user details from AD with "Application permissions" from an web app. Microsoft.Graph SDK 3.5 is used for this.

**.Net framework version** - 4.6.1

**Intermittently it is erroring out exception** :
"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure".

**On executing wireshark** : For failed API calls the graph.microsoft.com TLS certificate has an algorithm of sha384rsa while the successful ones are having sha256rsa.

How can be this be resolved?

Comment: Please let us know the document/GitHub sample you are referring to and share the code details where it's failing.

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question?

Comment: No got it resolved. Microsoft updated the root certificates for graph.microsoft.com